# Everytime I Run Dart in VS Code. It Shows This. Why? How can I fix it?

Tags: git, flutter, dart, upgrade, dart-pub

Whenever I Run My Dart code, It Shows me This Thing, for 1 - 2 Minutes and then It Runs for Me on my Machine,

```
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
```

And It Consumes a lot of time of mine, Can you Fix it.

Comment: Maybe try installing git? Flutter relies on git to update itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system requirements section lists `git` as a prerequisite. Maybe you skipped them?

If you are on Windows:

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Please read it carefully, and follow it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue in laptop after installing dart. actually flutter needs git so you have to install git on computer/laptop and need to restart it after installation.

this is link to install [git](https://git-scm.com/download/win) for windows.